# Should I send a thank you email for a mail informing me I have been shortlisted for an interview?

Tags: interviewing, professionalism, email-etiquette

I recently applied for a position and I received an email that I have been invited for an interview. The email suggests it has been sent to everyone shortlisted as it starts with 'Dear everyone,' and continues to say they will contact me in the next few days about the details.

I read online that sending thank you emails sends a positive message to the recruiter but I'm not sure where to draw the line over being polite and being over enthusiastic as I myself feel it is a bit extra at times.

Is it more appropriate to an email thanking them for informing me or wait till they send further details and then send a thank you email?

Comment: Maybe re-word this so you aren't asking us to make a specific choice for you. Without seeing the email it's hard to say what I would do. As it was addressed to multiple candidates, and they plan to send you a further invite, I don't think a reply is necessary. Being hypercritical it may look too enthusiastic, or a sign you think you're the centre of the universe. -- Ultimately it probably doesn't matter what you do, but I'd wait for the actual invite, then respond to that to confirm my availability and thank them for the invite within that email.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're going to send the information regardless of whether you respond or not.

Sending a "Thanks very much" email will be fine, but of course won't affect your chances of getting the job. You won't need to send another "thank you" email after you get the information pack.

I'd respond simply out of courtesy and politeness.

Answer (score 1):

A basic acknowledgement showing enthusiasm should do, IMO.

E.g. "Thank you, looking forward to it", or "Thanks, excited to take the next steps", or similar. (In addition to the usual salutations)

Answer (score 0):

I would respond with, "Thank you, and I look forward to hearing more regarding next-steps".

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to be clever and careful about the emails you send. If you're the first shortlisted candidate they may not be able to contact all the candidates as they've just started their hiring process.

If they say to you "everyone has been shortlisted and will be contacted in the next few days" you need to make sure that you never email them again. Let the opportunity to talk to the recruiter you've been referred to through your CV to do the talking.

For instance, if you're told "we will be in touch soon" and don't hear anything within a few days, you need to assume they've closed the process and be clever about the follow up emails you send.

For example:

I just saw you had emailed me a few days ago with the details of the interview. As I am the first shortlisted candidate, I wanted to thank you in advance for the time and effort you are putting into the process.

Thanks again,

You

Some candidates may take advantage of the bad practice of 'follow up emails' and open up a line of communication with the recruiter, putting them under pressure to give them the job.

Sending an email saying "I'll be waiting to hear from you" makes you look like a person who is desperate to get the job.